# "Demonstration of a test" – is that correct?

Tags: usage

Is the use of *demonstration* correct in the following sentence?

> The helicopter had **demonstrated** all planned tests.
>
> Source: [Article in *The Hindu*](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/light-utility-helicopter-close-to-certification-after-all-tests/article29341644.ece?homepage=true)

We usually demonstrate a quality, how one can demonstrate a test?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that demonstrate is usually used for a quality; however, it is most commonly used only with living things or personified things. Other nouns do not tend to use demonstrate.

A car, for example, does not demonstrate things. The driver inside may demonstrate its qualities.

In your above sentence about the helicopter, the word that be used is "performed."

Comment: Nice answer. And maybe it could be improved a bit. A car can demonstrate its age. By breaking down frequently, for example. *The diamond ring demonstrated how he felt about her.*

Comment: I think an even better word in this context might be _passed_. It's also worth noting that this "sentence" actually appears in a picture caption, where implied words are often omitted for the sake of brevity.

Comment: What if the car (or helicopter) is going through an automated series of tests, without there being any driver or pilot present? Would you resort to saying it would have to be the onboard computer or electronics doing the demonstration—or would you rule that out because those aren't sentient agents? I think that a vehicle without a human would more naturally *demonstrate* something (lights turning on and off, or whatever) than *perform* it. How can a vehicle *perform* anything?

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct.

However, things other than qualities can be demonstrated.

> He demonstrated the yoga pose as the students observed.
>
> The helicopter demonstrated the talent(s) of the engineering team.

But you're right. It doesn't make sense in that context.